# Remove disabled attr from button if text has value not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a multi-step popup form and only want the `#next` button to be active if the input fields are selected. I've managed to get it working for checkboxes and radio fields but for some reason it's not working for text and textarea fields.

I'm using the same code as the checkbox and radio fields but instead of checking `is(:checked)` I'm targeting `.val() != ""`.

When testing this, It only works if I go to the `.multi-step-section`, fill in the text field, go back to the previous screen and then back to the section with the field. I think the active class is still looking at the previous section.

Is there a way of checking to make sure the `input[type="text"]` and `input[type="textarea"]` fields are checked on the current active screen before disabling the button?

Link to full popup form: https://jsfiddle.net/5yd23jah/

```js
$(function() {
  $('.multi-form-actions button').on('click', function() {

    var el = $(this).attr('id');
    var active = $('.multi-step-section.active');

    active.add(active.siblings()).removeClass('active');

    if (el == 'prev') {
      active = active.prev('.multi-step-section').addClass('active');
      $('#progressbar > span').css({
        'width': $('#progressbar > span').width() / $('#progressbar').width() * 100 - sectionProgress + '%'
      });
    } else if (el = 'next') {
      active = active.next('.multi-step-section').addClass('active');
      $('#progressbar > span').css({
        'width': $('#progressbar > span').width() / $('#progressbar').width() * 100 + sectionProgress + '%'
      });
    }

    if ((active).find("input[type='radio'], input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked')) {
      $('#next').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else if ((active).find("input[type='text'], input[type='textarea']").val() != "") {
      console.log('not empty');
      $('#next').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
      $('#next').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }

    if (active.is(":not(:first-child)")) {
      $('#prev').show();
    } else {
      $('#prev').hide();
    }

    if (active.is(":last-child")) {
      $('#next').hide();
      $('#submit').show();
    } else {
      $('#next').show();
      $('#submit').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="multi-step-wrapper" id="multi-step">
  <div id="progressbar">
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="steps-inner">
    <div class="multi-step-section active" id="step1">
      <h3>Question 1</h3>
      <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap radio-185"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first"><label><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Loft</span><input name="radio-185[]" type="checkbox" value="Loft"></label>
        </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Garage ceiling</span><input name="radio-185[]" type="checkbox" value="Garage ceiling"></label>
        </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Floor</span><input name="radio-185[]" type="checkbox" value="Floor"></label>
        </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Ceilings</span><input name="radio-185[]" type="checkbox" value="Ceilings"></label>
        </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Stud walls</span><input name="radio-185[]" type="checkbox" value="Stud walls"></label>
        </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item last"><label><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Special project</span><input name="radio-185[]" type="checkbox" value="Special project"></label>
        </span>
        </span>
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="multi-step-section" id="step2">
      <h3>Question 2</h3>
      <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap text-465"><input aria-invalid="false" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" name="text-465" placeholder="Enter postcode, city or address" size="40" type="text" value=""></span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="multi-step-section" id="step3">
      <h3>Question 3</h3>
      <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap radio-187"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-radio"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first"><label><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">up to 30m2</span><input name="radio-187" type="radio" value="up to 30m2"></label>
        </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">30-60m2</span><input name="radio-187" type="radio" value="30-60m2"></label>
        </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">60-100m2</span><input name="radio-187" type="radio" value="60-100m2"></label>
        </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item last"><label><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">0ver 100m2</span><input name="radio-187" type="radio" value="0ver 100m2"></label>
        </span>
        </span>
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="multi-step-section" id="step4">
      <h3>Question 4</h3>
      <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap radio-188"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-radio"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first"><label><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Ready to go</span><input name="radio-188" type="radio" value="Ready to go"></label>
        </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">In the next couple of months</span><input name="radio-188" type="radio" value="In the next couple of months"></label>
        </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item last"><label><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">In a few months</span><input name="radio-188" type="radio" value="In a few months"></label>
        </span>
        </span>
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="multi-step-section" id="step5">
      <h3>Question 5</h3>
      <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap radio-189"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-radio"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first"><label><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Domestic</span><input name="radio-189" type="radio" value="Domestic"></label>
        </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Commercial</span><input name="radio-189" type="radio" value="Commercial"></label>
        </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item last"><label><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Construction</span><input name="radio-189" type="radio" value="Construction"></label>
        </span>
        </span>
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="multi-step-section" id="step6">
      <h3>Question 6</h3>
      <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap email-871"><input aria-invalid="false" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-email" name="email-871" placeholder="Enter your email address" size="40" type="email" value=""></span></p>
      <div>
        or
      </div>
      <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap tel-525"><input aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-tel wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-tel" name="tel-525" placeholder="Enter your telephone number" size="40" type="tel" value=""></span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="multi-form-actions">
    <button id="prev" type="button">Back</button><button disabled id="next" type="button">Continue</button><input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit multiform-submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Send"><br>
    <input class="sr-only" id="reset" type="reset">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no `type='textarea'`. `input[type='textarea']` is wrong.

Comment: Hi Adyson, thanks for your comment. The is(':checked') is working fine as i want the button to be disabled if at least one box is checked. I've included the full example here: https://jsfiddle.net/5yd23jah/

Comment: No, you're right. I hadn't appreciated that not all the questions would be shown at once, as the demo code doesn't hide them

Comment: Yeah apologies, i should've included the link when I first asked the question. I have to confess my js skills aren't the best and I'm still learning, so the code might be a bit heavy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean

```js
    var active = $('.multi-step-section.active');  
    var dis = active.find("input[type='radio']:checked").length == 0;
    dis = dis && active.find("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length == 0;
    dis = dis && active
      .find("input:text,textarea")
      .map(function(idx, elem) {
        return $(elem).val() || null; // beware of valid values of 0 (zero)
      }).get().length == 0;

    $('#next').prop('disabled', dis);
```

Code for progressbar:

```
  $('#pBar').prop("max",$('.multi-step-section').length).val(0); // loading
  ...
  $('#pBar').val(active.index()); // each click on the prev/next
```

**Running example**

```js
// reusable function
function checkInput() {
    var active = $('.multi-step-section.active');  
    var dis = active.find("input[type='radio']:checked").length == 0;
    dis = dis && active.find("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length == 0;
    dis = dis && active
      .find("input:text,textarea")
      .map(function(idx, elem) {
        return $(elem).val() || null;
      }).get().length == 0;

    $('#next').prop('disabled', dis);
}

$(function() {
  $(":input").on("input", checkInput); // any input 

  $('#pBar').prop("max",$('.multi-step-section').length).val(0);

  $('.multi-form-actions button').on('click', function() {

    var el = $(this).attr('id');
    var active = $('.multi-step-section.active');
    var count = $('.multi-step-section').length;
    active.add(active.siblings()).removeClass('active');

    if (el == 'prev') {
      active = active.prev('.multi-step-section').addClass('active');
    } else if (el = 'next') {
      active = active.next('.multi-step-section').addClass('active');
    }
    $('#pBar').val(active.index());


    checkInput(); // reset the continue if needed


    if (active.is(":not(:first-child)")) {
      $('#prev').show();
    } else {
      $('#prev').hide();
    }

    if (active.is(":last-child")) {
      $('#next').hide();
      $('#submit').show();
    } else {
      $('#next').show();
      $('#submit').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.multi-step-section {
  display: none
}

.active {
  display: block
}

#progressbar { background-color:green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="multi-step-wrapper" id="multi-step">
  <div id="progressbar">
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="steps-inner">
    <div class="multi-step-section active" id="step1">
      <h3>Question 1</h3>
      <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap radio-185"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first"><label><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Loft</span><input name="radio-185[]" type="checkbox" value="Loft"></label>
        </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Garage ceiling</span><input name="radio-185[]" type="checkbox" value="Garage ceiling"></label>
        </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Floor</span><input name="radio-185[]" type="checkbox" value="Floor"></label>
        </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Ceilings</span><input name="radio-185[]" type="checkbox" value="Ceilings"></label>
        </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Stud walls</span><input name="radio-185[]" type="checkbox" value="Stud walls"></label>
        </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item last"><label><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Special project</span><input name="radio-185[]" type="checkbox" value="Special project"></label>
        </span>
        </span>
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="multi-step-section" id="step2">
      <h3>Question 2</h3>
      <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap text-465"><input aria-invalid="false" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" name="text-465" placeholder="Enter postcode, city or address" size="40" type="text" value=""></span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="multi-step-section" id="step3">
      <h3>Question 3</h3>
      <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap radio-187"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-radio"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first"><label><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">up to 30m2</span><input name="radio-187" type="radio" value="up to 30m2"></label>
        </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">30-60m2</span><input name="radio-187" type="radio" value="30-60m2"></label>
        </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">60-100m2</span><input name="radio-187" type="radio" value="60-100m2"></label>
        </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item last"><label><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">0ver 100m2</span><input name="radio-187" type="radio" value="0ver 100m2"></label>
        </span>
        </span>
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="multi-step-section" id="step4">
      <h3>Question 4</h3>
      <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap radio-188"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-radio"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first"><label><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Ready to go</span><input name="radio-188" type="radio" value="Ready to go"></label>
        </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">In the next couple of months</span><input name="radio-188" type="radio" value="In the next couple of months"></label>
        </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item last"><label><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">In a few months</span><input name="radio-188" type="radio" value="In a few months"></label>
        </span>
        </span>
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="multi-step-section" id="step5">
      <h3>Question 5</h3>
      <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap radio-189"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-radio"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first"><label><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Domestic</span><input name="radio-189" type="radio" value="Domestic"></label>
        </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Commercial</span><input name="radio-189" type="radio" value="Commercial"></label>
        </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item last"><label><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Construction</span><input name="radio-189" type="radio" value="Construction"></label>
        </span>
        </span>
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="multi-step-section" id="step6">
      <h3>Question 6</h3>
      <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap email-871"><input aria-invalid="false" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-email" name="email-871" placeholder="Enter your email address" size="40" type="email" value=""></span></p>
      <div>
        or
      </div>
      <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap tel-525"><input aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-tel wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-tel" name="tel-525" placeholder="Enter your telephone number" size="40" type="tel" value=""></span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="multi-form-actions">
    <button id="prev" type="button">Back</button><button disabled id="next" type="button">Continue</button><input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit multiform-submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Send"><br>
    <input class="sr-only" id="reset" type="reset">
  </div>
</div>
<progress id="pBar" value="0">70 %</progress>
```

Comment: Not sure the `.is(':checked').length` logic is right here. The button needs to stay disabled until all the questions have been answered. So there needs to be at least one checked box / radio button _in each group_ before it can be enabled. Checking the status of all radio buttons together doesn't test that.

Comment: @ADyson updated. And each section is tested for the active section

Comment: good point. The demo code doesn't do the showing and hiding, so I hadn't appreciated that not all the questions would be shown at once.

Comment: I've replaced the conditional statement in my code with this and it works for checkboxes and radio. However, the #next button is always enabled for the text field even with no value?

Comment: @shaun  Please see update - note that I moved the function and test on input

Comment: @mplungjan thank you so much, this works! However, the progressbar has stopped working? The width value is always set to 0%. Does sectionProgress need to be reduced / incremented after every prev or next click as it starts at 0?

Comment: I did not see a progress bar. I made one that is simpler than yours - see update

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware that you could simply the progress bar with an HTML tag.